# ¿Cuál es el comando SQL para renombrar una base de datos de MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día tengan todos, estoy buscando la sentencia SQL para renombrar una base de datos mysql, pero en las indagaciones que he hecho todos me arrojan que:

- Usar la herramienta **phpMyAdmin** para renombrar la BD
- **Exportar** la base de datos y **crear uno nuevo** (con el  nuevo nombre de la base de datos).

Sinceramente no son respuestas aceptables.
¿Pueden decirme si realmente existe la sentencia para renombrar una BD Mysql?
Considero que las dos sugerencias que encontré no son aptas.

Answer (score 4):

No existe una instruccion SQL para renombrar una base de datos. El comando [ALTER DATABASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-database.html) solo permite ajustar ciertas propiedades de la base de datos pero no el nombre.

La solucion es usar una combinacion de CREATE DATABASE y [RENAME TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html) (las tablas se pueden mover de una base de  datos a otra usando RENAME). Un script completo tendra el siguiente contenido.

```
CREATE DATABASE new_db;
RENAME TABLE old_db.table1 TO new_db.table1;
RENAME TABLE old_db.table2 TO new_db.table2;
...
DROP DATABASE old_db;
```

Si el numero de tablas son muchas o deseas automatizar esto para cualquier base de datos, lo ideal es ejecutar un script que genere los renombrados de tablas:

```
for table in `mysql -u DBUSER -pDBPASS -s -N -e "show tables from old_db;"` 
do 
  mysql -u DBUSER -pDBPASS -s -N -e "RENAME TABLE old_db.$table to new_db.$table;"
done
```

Tambien se puede realizar en menos pasos usando el comando `mysqldump`:

```
mysql -u DBUSER -pDBPASS -e "CREATE DATABASE new_db"
mysqldump -u DBUSER -pDBPASS old_db | mysql -u DBUSER -pDBPASS -D new_db
```

Este comando genera una copia de respaldo completa de la base de datos original y la importa en una nueva base de datos (que debee haberse creado previamente, vacia)